# How to scale padding based on browser dimensions

Tags: html, ios, css

For the mobile viewing of my web site, I have decided to just show the social media icons. I would like the experience similar to that of using a mobile phone and choosing an app.

My goal is to keep it at 4 icons wide when viewed in portrait and 6 icons wide when viewed in landscape. The icons are 64x64 px and I do not want to scale them. With an image padding of 8, and with 4 icons across, it comes out to 320px total which is the minimum viewing I want allowed.

I know that 24 icons breaks the experience on smaller phones. I would have to offer the ability to swipe across to get to the next page of apps but that is another question.

I need help with CSS on making sure that at least 4 icons appear wide, but no more than 6 on a mobile device up to 768px. The padding should be minimum 8px but scale as the screen gets bigger. How can I accomplish this?

HTML

```
  <div class="screen">

    <div class="app"><a href="http://amazon.com" title="amazon"><img src="icons/amazon.png" alt="amazon"></a></div>
    <div class="app"><a href="http://dropbox.com" title="dropbox"><img src="icons/dropbox.png" alt="dropbox"></a></div>
    <div class="app"><a href="http://ebay.com" title="ebay"><img src="icons/ebay.png" alt="ebay"></a></div> 
    <div class="app"><a href="http://" title="email"><img src="icons/email.png" alt="email"></a></div>
    <div class="app clear4"><a href="http://" title="evernote"><img src="icons/evernote.png" alt="evernote"></a></div>
    <div class="app"><a href="http://" title="facebook"><img src="icons/facebook.png"></a></div>
    <div class="app clear6"><a href="http://" title="foursquare"><img src="icons/foursquare.png"></a></div>
    <div class="app"><a href="http://" title="friendfeed"><img src="icons/friendfeed.png"></a></div>
    <div class="app clear4"><a href="http://" title="github"><img src="icons/github.png"></a></div>
    <div class="app"><a href="http://" title="googleplus"><img src="icons/googleplus.png"></a></div>
    <div class="app"><a href="http://" title="instagram"><img src="icons/instagram.png"></a></div>
    <div class="app"><a href="http://" title="linkedin"><img src="icons/linkedin.png"></a></div>
    <div class="app clear4"><a href="http://" title="paypal"><img src="icons/paypal.png"></a></div>
    <div class="app"><a href="http://" title="pinterest"><img src="icons/pinterest.png"></a></div>
    <div class="app clear6"><a href="http://" title="skype"><img src="icons/skype.png"></a></div>
    <div class="app"><a href="http://" title="stackoverflow"><img src="icons/stackoverflow.png"></a></div>
    <div class="app clear4"><a href="http://" title="stumleupon"><img src="icons/stumbleupon.png"></a></div>
    <div class="app"><a href="http://" title="tumblr"><img src="icons/tumblr.png"></a></div>
    <div class="app clear6"><a href="http://" title="twitter"><img src="icons/twitter.png"></a></div>
    <div class="app"><a href="http://" title="vimeo"><img src="icons/vimeo.png"></a></div>
    <div class="app clear4"><a href="http://" title="vine"><img src="icons/vine.png"></a></div>
    <div class="app"><a href="http://" title="wordpress"><img src="icons/wordpress.png"></a></div>
    <div class="app"><a href="http://" title="yelp"><img src="icons/yelp.png" alt="yelp"></a></div>
    <div class="app"><a href="http://" title="youtube"><img src="icons/youtube-2.png" alt="youtube"></a></div>

  </div><!-- .apps -->
```

CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width: 319px) {
  /* display notice */
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 768px) {

  .screen img {
    float: left;
    min-padding: 8px;
  }

  .clear4 {
    clear: both;
  }

}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {

  /* show other content */

  /* max 6 cols, 4 rows */
}
```

Here is an image of the icons (no padding) in portrait mode to get an idea.

[image]

Edit: So I was able to figure out the 4 and 6 columns based on orientation. Now I need help with scaling the padding.

Comment: I was thinking it might help if I used multiple css files, one for portrait and one for landscape on mobile devices and one for desktop. Otherwise, I would need to use PHP or JS to add logic in cutting off the 4th or 6th icon based on orientation and size.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is with intrinsictive rations check [Here is a basic template I made up](https://jsfiddle.net/bb660g53/) and this is what yours should/would be needs editing though because I do not have your project files.

If you need anymore help with this let me know.

EDIT: I forgot you need 10 rep for more then 2 links so just replace the jsfiddle link with this /e4vyu4vb/1/ to see the version for your project.

Code if you cannot access JSfiddle
Template: (the one without your code)
CSS

```
    .intrinsictive-ration {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 20%;
    height: 0;
}
    .elements-you-need-stretched {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: grey;  /* you will need to adjust this to your liking */
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="intrinsictive-ration">
<!-- this it the main div -->
  <div class="elements-you-need-stretched"></div>
</div>
<!-- ending of the main div -->
```

Comment: This did not work for me. It doesn't limit the 4 icons or 6 icons.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want the resolution to be the determinining factor in the scaling of the padding? If that is the case I can not think of any possible way to do so outside of PHP or maybe JS

Comment: Well I can't use PHP  - if the user rotates the screen, it would have to reload the page. Javascript might be the better choice.